# What will be the key when I insert the data in Ignite cache using insert Script

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, ignite

**Can please someone clarify my doubts on Ignite cache. I have checked the Ignite docs but these things are not mentioned:**

1. I am inserting data in Ignite cache using insert script. I want to know how I can fetch the same data using Ignite get APIs. What will be my key to fetch the data.
2. If I use the Ignite API to store the data, I am creating a key with  new keyword as new Key(1,"test") and the then put(key,DataObject), and now If I want to get the same object I again need to pass key after creating key object like new Key(2,"test") and then get(key).
   But here I dont understand is that in both cases we are creating new objects with new keyword how they are returning the correct object because hash code will be different for the keys used in store and fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite will compare keys in their [BinaryObject](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/key-value-api/binary-objects) form.